# How to correctly check if a toggleButton is currently selected on Chrome console using jQuery commands?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

There's [this page](https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/) that displays the economic calendar for `Today` by default:

[image]

I'm trying to find a `jQuery` method that returns `true` or `false` depending on weather the toggleButton called `Today` is currently selected.

I tried the following method on `Chrome Console`:

```
$('#timeFrame_today').is(':selected')
```

And it returned:

> false

Which should not be the case since as I mentioned, the `#timeFrame_today` button (a.k.a. `Today`) is selected by default, so I'm lost here.

Comment: `:selected` is for `<option>` elements per jQuery documentation. In this case you can use devtools inspector to see what's different about this element. It has `toggled` class so you can check it via `$('#timeFrame_today').hasClass('toggled')`

Comment: Oh! I had not noticed that class value, it all makes sense now, thank you @wOxxOm